# ¿Como puedo obtener la fecha de un datepicker utilizando angular 2?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, typescript, datepicker

Tengo un datepicker y necesito obtener la fecha para poder guardarla pero no tengo idea como hacerlo, si alguien me puede ,adjunto el codigo del plugin

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fecha"> {{'Fecha' | i18n}}</label>
                        <input type="text" #fecha="ngModel" (blur)="convocatoria.fecha=fecha.value" [(ngModel)]="convocatoria.fecha" name="fecha"
                          id="fecha" class="form-control datepicker" [saUiDatepicker]="{
                                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
                             }" required>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que seria algo mas o menos así:

```
fecha() {
  let fechaActual = new Date();
  let dia = fechaActual.getDate().toString();
  let mes = (fechaActual.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  let anio = fechaActual.getFullYear().toString();
  let hora = fechaActual.getHours().toString();
  let minutos = fechaActual.getMinutes().toString();
  let segundos = fechaActual.getSeconds().toString();
  this.Fecha = anio + "-" + mes + "-" + dia;
  this.Hora = hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas. Deberías de poder acceder al valor de tu fecha desde su ngModel

```
[(ngModel)]="convocatoria.fecha"
```

Es decir si en el component.ts accedes a ella mediante `this.convocatoria.fecha`